# select option value send to php file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a select dropdown box

```
<select name="status" id="status" onchange="changeStatus()">
    <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
    <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
    <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
    <option value="step_4">step_4</option>
</select>
```

And my javascript

```
<script>
    function changeStatus() {
        $('select.changeStatus').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'update_status.php',
                    data: {changeStatus: $('select.changeStatus').val()},
                    dataType: 'html'
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I want the value selected from the select dropdown box send to the php file(update_status.php)

Comment: So, the code you provided doesn't work or what?

Comment: I have a little question...will on change overload the http request ??

Comment: yes it doesn't work@Epodax

Comment: onchenge the selected option send to the php file

Answer (score 0):

$('#status').val() is used to get value of select options.

So try this

```
<script>
    function changeStatus() {
        $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'update_status.php',
                    data: {changeStatus: $('#status').val()},
                    dataType: 'html'
             });
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>

function changeStatus() {
    $.post("update_status.php", {changeStatus: $('#status').val()}, function(data, status){

    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: By using attribute onchange="changeStatus()" is it call the function properly???   @ Ijas

Comment: Since you are giving onchange="changeStatus()" in select, function will execute. If you want to test give console.log($('#status').val()) inside changeStatus() function

Comment: But then it should be redirect to that page(update_status.php) anyway

Comment: I mostly use post method to send request to php scripts. I dont know ajax formats. I have updated the solution with post method. It will be a working code. You can get changeStatus value in php script as $_POST["changeStatus"]

Answer (score 0):

Select id using `#`. Since you are already using javascript onchange event in select field so no need to use jquery `change()` event. jQuery use `#` to select id and `.` to select class. since you are using `id="status"` so you must use `#` to select the id. The way you are trying to collect the value of the select field in this line `$('select.changeStatus').val()` is wrong. Because there are no class named `changeStatus` there.

```
function changeStatus() {

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update_status.php',
                data: {changeStatus: $('#select').val()},
                dataType: 'html'

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mix jQuery and inline JS

HTML - we'll use your selects name in the function. I've removed the inline function call:

```
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
    <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
    <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
    <option value="step_4">step_4</option>
</select>
```

jQuery - I have taken the code out of the function you were calling inline, it was not needed.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="status"]').change(function(){
            var status = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'update_status.php',
                    data: {changeStatus: status},
                    dataType: 'html'
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can directly test when the `select` changes and grab its value right then. Here is an [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kq0ye7vf/)

I have also wrapped the jQuery in a document ready handler. Depending on where you're loading the script in your page you may need to do this to make sure that your jQuery is run as soon as the DOM elements have been loaded.

Comment: Yes its work with alert but it wasn't post to the php file with your given code(2nd part)  @Jay

Comment: Did you watch the request / response in the console? I made a small edit to capture the value in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onchange field from select and put the below code to your script and this is working. Use JQuery post functionality instead.

```
$("#status").change( function() {

    alert($( this ).val());
    $.post('update_status.php', { changeStatus: $(this).val()},      
         function(response) {
         console.log( response);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       <select name="status" id="status" onchange="changeStatus(this.value)">
            <option value="step_1">step_1</option>
            <option value="step_2">step_2</option>
            <option value="step_3">step_3</option>
            <option value="step_4">step_4</option>
        </select>


function changeStatus(value) {

        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'update_status.php',
                data: {'get_data:value'},
                success: function (response) {
                       document.getElementById("loadto").innerHTML=response; 
                     }

        });
}
```

I Hope it will be helpful .....